# Protractor: Specified suite is not running .Instead all suite inside Suites(config.js) is running

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, jasmine

**Test Case:** 
I wanted to run only one suite (eg) suite 'A'. So i specified the same while running configuration  `protractor conf.js -- suites A`

**Problem:**  All Suites (A,B,C,D) are running, instead of just suite A.

**NOTE:**  Running individual Spec works correctly. So Spec code issue.

**Config File Excerpt:**

```
     var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
     var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
     var fs = require('fs');

    exports.config = {

framework: 'jasmine2',
directConnect: true,
capabilities: {

    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['incognito', '--start-maximized'],  // this line is for maximize the window and incognito view

        prefs: {
            'profile:managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser'],
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': 'C:/Users/kesavara/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/Workspace/Reports/Download/'
            },
        },
    },
},
allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
suites: {
  A: ['./Spec/Find_Account_Page/FindAccount_By_AccountInfo.js', './Spec/Find_Account_Page/FindAccount_By_UserInfo.js'],
    B :'./Spec/LIST/*Spec.js',
       C:'./Spec/USER_ROLES/ACCMANG_USER_Role/*Spec.js',                                                                             D: './Spec/USER_ROLES/ADMIN_USER_Role/*Spec.js',         
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    displaySpecDuration: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 260000,
    print: function () {
    }
},

onPrepare: function(){
    browser.manage().window().maximize();          // set browser size...

    global.isAngularSite = function(flag){
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    };
   // Remove files in Specified Directory

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true,
            displayFailuresSummary: true
        }
    }));
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I've done this with protractor in the past is like...

single suite `protractor config.js --suite A`

multiple suites `protractor config.js --suite A,B,C`

Note: commas but no spaces between suite names

I'm personally not sure that `--suites` is valid in protractor CLI

Answer (score 0):

**Need to enclose every suite in a separate square brackets.**

```
suites: {
  A: ['./Spec/Find_Account_Page/FindAccount_By_AccountInfo.js', './Spec/Find_Account_Page/FindAccount_By_UserInfo.js'],
  B: ['./Spec/LIST/*Spec.js'],
  C: ['./Spec/USER_ROLES/ACCMANG_USER_Role/*Spec.js'],
  D: ['./Spec/USER_ROLES/ADMIN_USER_Role/*Spec.js']         
 },
```